# How can I smoothly move a marker (Feature) from one location to another with OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, javascript, openstreetmap

I want to move a marker (a Feature object) from one location to another with animation. So I don't want the location pops up from one place to another, because it's not userfriendly. What I hope to achieve is that a marker slides from one position on the map to another.
This is my example of a marker:

```
let chopter = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([4.333959, 52.060110]))
});
```

What I want is a smooth motion of the marker from one position to another. How can I achieve that?

Comment: See https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-move-animation.html

Comment: This is a bit hard to understand. vectorLayer.on('postrender', moveFeature); calls moveFeature everytime vector-layer has changed?

Comment: Yes, but it applies only to `moveFeature` feature during the move,  it is removed after move is finished by `vectorLayer.un('postrender', moveFeature)`.